# How to process multiple files in a loop?

Tags: python, regex, loops, file-handling

I'm trying to create a loop that searches the current directory for all .txt files and then adds the data in those files to a dictionary. Up until now, I've only needed to open one file at a time so I'm not entirely sure how this would be done. Can I use regex to match file types and open them that way?

Edit: The data I'm supposed to parse with Regex is a bunch of websites with pageview counts. I'm to build a dictionary using the page_title as the key, with the sum of count_views to that page as the value. There are other requirements for the assignment but they're just different ways of sorting and displaying the data I've collected from my original question.

TLDR- I need to make one dictionary from multiple files of data and be able to sort and display the contents of the dictionary

Comment: You don't need to do anything fundamentally different -- use `os.listdir()` to get a list of files that you can loop over, and then read each file individually.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: How is the data being stored in the dictionary? There isn't enough information in your question for anyone to really answer it…

Answer (score 1):

As people have hinted at there are some pending questions that will change the implementation of the code. I'll make a few assumptions:

1. Each file can have multiple websites, one per line
2. The page_title and view count are separated by a space
3. The view count is an integer

Given these assumptions, the directory structure would looks something like this:

```
testdir/
├── first_data.txt
└── second_data.txt
```

With the contents of a data file looking like so:

```
www.google.com 43
www.youtube.com 50
```

Given the following conditions, you could:

- Get a list of files in the directory using os.listdir
- Iterate through each file, ignoring the files that don't end in .txt
- Read the data from each matching file
- Process the data by line breaks and spaces (the TODO in the code shows where you would need to change things given a different data format)
- Add the data to the result dictionary

The following code will process the data given the conditions described above:

```
import os


def get_website_data(directory):
    website_data_dict = {}

    files = os.listdir(directory)
    # iterate through each file in the directory
    for file in files:
        # skip if the file isn't a text file
        if not file.endswith(".txt"):
            continue
        path = os.path.join(directory, file)
        # open the file
        with open(path, "r") as data:
            # iterate through each line of the file
            # TODO: change logic based on actual file storage
            for line in data:
                website_data = line.split(" ")
                page_title = website_data[0]
                views = int(website_data[1])
                if page_title in website_data_dict:
                    website_data_dict[page_title] += views
                else:
                    website_data_dict[page_title] = views
    return website_data_dict


def main():
    data_directory = "./testdir"
    website_data = get_website_data(data_directory)
    print(f'Website Data: {website_data}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```